# GetOldTweets-pythonについて

Tags: python3

現在、Twitterの過去のツイートを遡り取得しようとしています。
そこでQiita（https://qiita.com/haniokasai/items/9eba9e232a144a0f8805）で発見したGetOldTweets-pythonを使用し、Colab上で取得しようと試みたのですが、うまくインストールができていないようなのですがどうすればいいでしょうか？
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: よく見たら `GetOldTweests-python` になっていますね(typo)。それから、ディレクトリを移動する場合は `!` ではなく `%` を使うと良いです。`%cd GetOldTweets-python`

Comment: 追伸: こちらで試した限りでは `pyquery` モジュールをインストールする必要がありました。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。お恥ずかしながらタイプミスもあったようで…。教えていただいた方法を試したら上手く動作しました！ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Jupyter Notebook`でのディレクトリの移動は、`os.chdir`又はマジックコマンド`%cd`を使っておこないます。以下でインストールできると思います。

```
!git clone https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python
!pip install lxml pyquery
import os
os.chdir('GetOldTweets-python')
import got3 as got
```